# mySql - Make a select with condition on group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some data like these:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idDoc` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `idProd` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `codProd` text NOT NULL,
  `qta` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `serNum` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lotto` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SNLTdett` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `merce` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PArticoli'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `idDoc`, `idProd`, `codProd`, `qta`, `serNum`, `lotto`, `SNLTdett`, `merce`) VALUES
(22856, 1262, 4069, 'COMPOSTO', 2, '', 'AAA', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22857, 1262, 4066, 'COMUNE', 4, '', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22858, 1262, 4061, 'FIGL1', 3, '', 'AAA', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22859, 1262, 4062, 'FIGL2', 3, '', 'BBB', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22860, 1262, 4068, 'LOTTO', 8, '', 'AAA', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22861, 1262, 4068, 'LOTTO', 4, '', 'BBB', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22862, 1262, 4067, 'SERIALE', 1, 'E', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22863, 1262, 4067, 'SERIALE', 1, 'C', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22864, 1262, 4067, 'SERIALE', 1, 'D', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22865, 1262, 4067, 'SERIALE', 1, 'A', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22866, 1262, 4067, 'SERIALE', 1, 'B', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22867, 1262, 4063, 'SNLT-1', 1, 'BBB', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22868, 1262, 4063, 'SNLT-1', 1, 'AAA', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22869, 1262, 4064, 'SNLT-1B', 1, 'RRR', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22870, 1262, 4064, 'SNLT-1B', 1, 'SSS', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22854, 1262, 4066, 'COMUNE', 2, '', '', '', 'PAccessori'),
(22855, 1262, 142, 'CAPSNLT', 2, '', '', '', 'anaVcap'),
(22853, 1262, 4067, 'SERIALE', 1, 'Q', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22852, 1262, 4067, 'SERIALE', 1, 'Z', '', '', 'PArticoli'),
(22873, 1262, 0, '', 1, '', '', '', 'varie');
```

I would like to have all the rows but the sum of qta only for the rows that have same idProd and merce and serNum !=''
like these:

```
idDoc   idProd  codProd     qta   serNum          lotto     merce
1262    142     CAPSNLT     2                               anaVcap
1262    4069    COMPOSTO    2                     AAA       PArticoli
1262    4066    COMUNE      4                               PArticoli
1262    4066    COMUNE      2                               PAccessori
1262    4061    FIGL1       3                     AAA       PArticoli
1262    4062    FIGL2       3                     BBB       PArticoli
1262    4068    LOTTO       8                     AAA       PArticoli
1262    4068    LOTTO       4                     BBB       PArticoli
1262    4067    SERIALE     7     E,C,D,A,B,Q,Z             PArticoli
1262    4063    SNLT-1      2     BBB,AAA                   PArticoli
1262    4064    SNLT-1B     2     RRR,SSS                   PArticoli
```

I have made this query

```
SELECT idDoc, idProd, codProd, SUM(qta), lotto, SNLTdett,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(serNum='','', serNum)) AS srnSch
FROM test 
WHERE idDoc=1262 AND (merce='PArticoli' OR merce='PAccessori' OR merce='anaVcap') 
GROUP BY idProd, merce
```

and it give me:

```
idDoc   idProd  codProd     qta   serNum          lotto     merce
1262    142     CAPSNLT     2                               anaVcap
1262    4069    COMPOSTO    2                     AAA       PArticoli
1262    4066    COMUNE      4                               PArticoli
1262    4066    COMUNE      2                               PAccessori
1262    4061    FIGL1       3                     AAA       PArticoli
1262    4062    FIGL2       3                     BBB       PArticoli
1262    4068    LOTTO       12                    AAA       PArticoli
1262    4067    SERIALE     7     E,C,D,A,B,Q,Z             PArticoli
1262    4063    SNLT-1      2     BBB,AAA                   PArticoli
1262    4064    SNLT-1B     2     RRR,SSS                   PArticoli
```

my problem is that I need:

```
22860   1262    4068    LOTTO       8               AAA     PArticoli
22861   1262    4068    LOTTO       4               BBB     PArticoli
```

My condition is : same (idProd and merce) and serNum !=''

How I can do it? How I can insert as condition serNum !='' in GROUP BY?

Here the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c2df/9

Comment: *my problem is that I need* Add `lotto` into GROUP BY expression.

Comment: I can't do this because the lotto must always be separated... if there are 2 same lotto they must be separated

Comment: If so then group  additionally by something like ```CASE WHEN `lotto` != '' THEN RAND() ELSE 0 END``` - this will collapse the rows only when `lotto` is empty string.

Comment: Can you write me the query? I don't know CASE WHEN...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: Note that MyISAM ceased to be the default engine a decade ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra condition in the `GROUP BY` using the [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case) expression. Here I assume that `id` is unique.

```
CASE WHEN serNum='' THEN id ELSE 0 END
```

this expression returns different (unique) IDs for the rows where `serNum` is empty, so all these rows will remain separate. All rows where `serNum` is not empty will get the same `0` value, so they can be grouped together.

Overall the query would look like this: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c2df/19)

```
SELECT 
    MIN(idDoc) AS idDoc
    , idProd
    , MIN(codProd) AS codProd
    , SUM(qta)
    , MIN(lotto) AS lotto
    , MIN(SNLTdett) AS SNLTdett
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(serNum='','', serNum)) AS srnSch
FROM test 
WHERE idDoc=1262 AND merce IN ('PArticoli', 'PAccessori', 'anaVcap') 
GROUP BY idProd, merce, CASE WHEN serNum='' THEN id ELSE 0 END
ORDER BY codProd;
```

**Results**

```
| idDoc | idProd |  codProd | SUM(qta) | lotto | SNLTdett |        srnSch |
|-------|--------|----------|----------|-------|----------|---------------|
|  1262 |    142 |  CAPSNLT |        2 |       |          |               |
|  1262 |   4069 | COMPOSTO |        2 |   AAA |          |               |
|  1262 |   4066 |   COMUNE |        2 |       |          |               |
|  1262 |   4066 |   COMUNE |        4 |       |          |               |
|  1262 |   4061 |    FIGL1 |        3 |   AAA |          |               |
|  1262 |   4062 |    FIGL2 |        3 |   BBB |          |               |
|  1262 |   4068 |    LOTTO |        8 |   AAA |          |               |
|  1262 |   4068 |    LOTTO |        4 |   BBB |          |               |
|  1262 |   4067 |  SERIALE |        7 |       |          | E,C,D,A,B,Q,Z |
|  1262 |   4063 |   SNLT-1 |        2 |       |          |       BBB,AAA |
|  1262 |   4064 |  SNLT-1B |        2 |       |          |       RRR,SSS |
```

Comment: You save me... I have also understood that there is another method to put in WHERE... IN (...) thanks a lot! Just a question: why MIN(...)?

Comment: @FrancescoG., you are welcome. `MIN`? You know better what aggregation should be there. When you have a `GROUP BY` clause, then all columns in `SELECT` part that are not included in `GROUP BY` should be inside an aggregation function (min, max, sum, avg, etc.). If you don't do that then it is a syntax error in all DBMS, except MySQL. So, either include a column in `GROUP BY`, or wrap it in a function; otherwise the query doesn't make sense. It is a very annoying "feature" of MySQL when it silently ignores such syntax error and returns some not well-defined value.